# Prolog Permutations with Condition for Multiple Elements

Tags: prolog, permutation

I have a program to generate all the permutations of a list where for each `2<=i<=n`, there is a `1<=j<i` where `|v(i)-v(j)|=1`

For example, for `[1,2,3]`, the results are:

```
[1,2,3]
[2,1,3]
[2,3,1]
[3,2,1]
```

`[1,3,2]` and `[3,1,2]` would be wrong because `|3-1|` and `|1-3|` are not `1`

The code is:

```
takeout([X|T],X,T).
takeout([H|L],X,[H|T]) :-
    takeout(L,X,T).

takeout1([X|T],P,X,T) :-
    D is abs(X-P),
    D =:= 1.
takeout1([H|L],N,X,[H|T]) :-
    takeout1(L,N,X,T).

perm1([],[]).
perm1(L,[E|T]) :-
    takeout(L,E,R),
    perm_abs(R,E,T).

perm_abs([],_,[]).
perm_abs(L,O,[E|T]) :-
    takeout1(L,O,E,R),
    perm_abs(R,E,T).

perm(N,R):-
    numlist(1,N,L),
    perm1(L,R).
```

This code gives only the consecutive results. I think I am supposed to change something at takeout1, but I do not know where exactly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are `i` and `j` here? It is not perfectly clear to me what your constraint is.

Comment: Furthermore given your original list contains only `[1,2,...,k]`, indeed the only permutations that are valid are `[1,2,...,k]` and `[k,k-1,...1]`, since every other "swap" will result in a "gap" somewhere else.

Comment: *for each 2<=`i`<=`n`, there is a 1<=`j`...* What do these variables `i`, `n`, and `j` represent in this condition?

Comment: "i" are the numbers from the second position of the list to the last one, and "j" are the numbers before "i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
valid(R) :-
    forall((nth1(I,R,X), I>1), (nth1(J,R,Y), J<I, 1 =:= abs(X-Y))).

?- forall((N=4, numlist(1,N,L), permutation(L,R), valid(R)),writeln(R)).
[1,2,3,4]
[2,1,3,4]
[2,3,1,4]
[2,3,4,1]
[3,2,1,4]
[3,2,4,1]
[3,4,2,1]
[4,3,2,1]
true.
```

You can add valid/1 after the intermediate permutation step, to get early filtering of invalid configurations.

Comment: It works for N = 3, but for N = 4, it writes the result twice and it also writes [1,4,3,2], which is wrong, because |4-1|=3, not 1. For N=5 it writes the result three times and also gives some wrong answers

Comment: Sorry, my bad... now should work. Check it out. Anyway, the idea is to separate the validity check from the generation.